# apparantly inconsistent partition table in Ubuntu liveUSB

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, mbr, startup-disk-creator

I recently created a bootable live Ubuntu USB and I chose to create it with the Startup Disk Creator natively offered by Ubuntu. Everything went along with and the Ubuntu even booted properly. But when I took a peek at the partition table I was completely lost. To check the partition table I executed the command

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

and the output I received was

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x05e037df

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 3112959 3112960  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       3089492 3094291    4800  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

This got me confused because as you can see the /dev/sdb2 partition is embedded inside /dev/sdb1 partition. I do not expect this to work. Also, the first partition starts at byte 0 so there is practically no space left for MBR. Yet, this usb boots well. What could be going on?

Comment: It seems that you are looking at a [hybrid GPT](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hybrid_partition_table)-partitioned disk; those kind of disks can be seen as MBR-partitioned for booting using BIOS, or as GPT-partitioned for booting using EFI.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing on that usb stick, you can delete and recreate it all over again. This is automatic configuration, sdb2 is sandwiched inside sdb1 range. 
"SDB1-SDB2-SDB1" format. Why ? Not sure why it did this.. MBR does not show up in the partition table to my knowledge.